# chrome extension chrome.tabs.update callback functions tab loading status is always "Loading"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to update current tab id with a new URL through chrome.tabs.update.

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabpid, {url: "https://www.google.com"}, function(tab){
                console.log(tab.status);//This is always in loading status
                console.log("Load Pending");
                if(tab.status == "complete"){
                     console.log("Load complete");
                    //Do something
                }
            });
```

I want to know when the tab has finished loading.

tab.status is always pending...How to know when the tab has finished loading through chrome.tabs.update?

I tried chrome.tabs.onupdated.addlistener, that seems to work with the tabid, but it fires every single time any tab is opened by user.

I just need the status on callback function, is this anyway possible ?

Comment: [Chrome extensions : How to know when a tab has finished loading, from the background page](//stackoverflow.com/a/44864966) or use a simple setInterval that invokes chrome.tabs.get